# Weak/Strong "dance" in Manual Memory Management

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Imagine the following scenario using **Manual Memory Management** (aka non-ARC):

I have a VC that passes a block to a class method. Before the block being executed, the VC is popped up out of a `UINavigationController`. A weak reference in the form of `__block MyVC *weakSelf = self` is passed to the block which is then converted to `MyVC *strongSelf = weakSelf` (aka weak/strong dance). The block is never retained by any of the intervenients.

In this scenario, what I am seeing in my code is:

1. The dealloc of the VC is called when it is popped out.
2. The block is eventually is called.
3. The app crashes because I am accessing garbage (the `strongSelf` is pointing to it).

My question is: I don't want my VC to stay alive until the block eventually executes, but once the block is executed I want to confirm that `strongSelf` is valid.

I have checked this ([non-trivial example by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)) which doesn't work because it's designed with ARC in mind. So how can I have the same behaviour with MMM?  Ideally I want to have what `__weak` does: if the `retainCount` reaches zero, I want its references to point to nil and not to garbage.

---

After reading this from Apple:

> In some cases you can use __unsafe_unretained if the class isn’t
>   __weak compatible. This can, however, become impractical for nontrivial cycles because it can be hard or impossible to validate
>   that the __unsafe_unretained pointer is still valid and still points
>   to the same object in question.

Since I don't have access to `__weak` what I want to do is even possible?

Comment: @trojanfoe the point it know if it's safe to call methods inside the block. In case the VC is gone, it will crash, in case it still exists it will work as expected.

Comment: You can do what you are trying to achieve, but it's not trivial. I'm writing out an answer as I had to tackle this same problem a couple of years back. Stay tuned!

Comment: @trojanfoe if I would do that, I would have to verify everywhere if the block is `NULL` before trying to execute it.

Comment: That block can be executed in 3 different places, so I would have to verify in those 3 places, no?

Comment: @trojanfoe so I am essentially wrapping the block in another block? :/

Answer (score 1):

I battled with this exact issue back in the iOS 4.x days. It's not easy without weak pointers giving you a hand!

If you are guaranteed that block is executed on the main thread at a later point (i.e. where strongSelf is assigned from weakSelf) then you basically need a place to store a "isDead" flag, which you set when the VC is dealloced. You then check this flag before doing anything with weakSelf/strongSelf. One solution is this:

1. You need a class who's only job is to store this "isDead" flag in a member variable. Something like a NSMutableBoolean. I won't write one out, it's simple enough, it just needs a single `BOOL` property.
2. In your VC's `-[NSObject init]` method you create an instance of this flag object, which should initially be set to `false`.
3. You then pass this object through to any block you queue for later execution, such that it is automatically retained/released by the block (i.e. without going through the weak/strong dance). Inside the block, you check if the flag is still `NO` before doing anything with weakSelf.
4. The key of course is to set the flag to `YES` inside the VC's `-[NSObject dealloc]` method, and then release it. If any blocks are still pending execution, they will have already retained the flag object themselves, and when they are later executed they will query the flag discover that the VC is now dead.

This sounds cumbersome (and it is, a bit) but the idea is that the "isDead" flag lives *outside* the scope of the VC and is therefore not tied to it's lifetime. As for thread safety, as long as you only set/query the flag inside the VC's init/dealloc method and when the block is executed (on the main thread, not on a background thread) it will be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want my VC to stay alive until the block eventually executes

But why does it matter? The memory of one VC shouldn't be that much, and if the block performs any UI actions on the VC, that's okay too, since the VC isn't displayed anyway.

Basically, the block should not capture a weak reference to the VC if the VC doesn't retain the block. Using non-zeroing weak reference means you guarantee that the object will stay alive, which is not the case here. I would suggest you not do this weak thing.

Comment: You are making an assumption: `block performs any UI actions on the VC, that's okay too, since the VC isn't displayed anyway`, what if it has some heavy side effects? Images fetching? What I am trying to avoid is extra work where it isn't needed.